# how to select min of string from list c#

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose we have List s = new List{"ABCDEF","ABC", "ABCD"};
here the output should be ABC but I am getting ABCDEF

TRIED Min() method using LINQ C# and received ABCDEF as the output.

I NEED "ABC" as output. ANY HELP?

Comment: Post an [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718458/find-the-shortest-string-in-an-array-of-string

Comment: Works for me - s.Min() gives "ABC", s.Max() gives "ABCDEF".

 https://dotnetfiddle.net/8GcMxg

Comment: try this  s.OrderBy(str => str).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @emrahkaraman This has already been suggested in an answer _and_ downvoted ...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few elements there. You can use `Min()` here, but format it correctly.

```
        List<string> s = new List<string>{"ABCDEF","ABC", "ABCD"};
        Console.WriteLine(s.Min());
```

Remember about correct using statements:

```
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: OP has said this is what was tried & gave the wrong result - can you explain why your version works when it didn't for OP.

Comment: @PaulF Well, now I see your comment there, I would think there was some typo and the OP actually called Max instead of Min, especially since the syntax in the OP's message is a little bit twisted. To be honest, I don't see any other option there.

Answer (score -1):

In C#, the Min() method used with strings will return the minimum value based on their lexicographical (dictionary) order. In this case, "ABC" is lexicographically greater than "ABCD" and "ABCDEF," so "ABC" is considered the minimum value, not "ABCDEF."

If you want to find the shortest string in the list instead of the lexicographically smallest, you can use LINQ to achieve that. Here's how you can do it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> s = new List<string> { "ABCDEF", "ABC", "ABCD" };
        string shortestString = s.OrderBy(str => str.Length).First();
        Console.WriteLine(shortestString); // Output: ABC
    }
}
```

In this code, we are using the OrderBy() method to sort the strings based on their length in ascending order. Then, we use the First() method to get the first (shortest) string from the sorted list, which will be "ABC" in this case.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).